# Not able to save multiple results into my table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database

I am working on ASP.NET MVC project. This is my code :

```
orderData_Entities ordertable = new orderData_Entities();
DataTable upCSV = (DataTable)TempData["UploadedCSV"];

if (isHeaderAccepted)
{
   string[] data = null;
   int i = 1;

   foreach (DataRow dr in upCSV.Rows)
   {
       ObjectParameter getemail = new ObjectParameter("email", dr["email"].ToString());
       ObjectParameter getpassword = new ObjectParameter("password", dr["password"].ToString());
       ObjectParameter getMobile = new ObjectParameter("Mobile", dr["Mobile"].ToString());

       var results = ordertable.usp_AppUpdateUserData(idSubAccount,idcategory,  getemail.Value.ToString(), getpassword.Value.ToString(), getMobile.Value.ToString());

       ordertable.SaveChanges();
       i++;
    }
}

return RedirectToAction("Index", "BulkUpload");
```

Here I am looping through all rows and updating results to my table. Currently what's happening here is if I have three rows with email, password and mobile, it is looping through all these three rows one by one and I can see results in debug mode, but while updating to my table, it is updating last row results to all three rows.

So can someone tell me what mistake I am doing here?

Update : 
My Stored Procedure is as follows :

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AppUpdateUserData]

 @idSubAccount int = 0,
 @idcategory int = 0,
 @email nvarchar(100) =0, 
 @password nvarchar(50) = 0, 
  @Mobile nvarchar(50) = 0,


 AS
BEGIN

Begin
Update tblCustomer
Set  
email = @email, password = @password, mobileNo = @Mobile, 

 where idSubAccount = @idSubAccount and idCategory = @idcategory


 END
 End

  GO
```

Comment: can you please detail out your ordertable.usp_AppUpdateUserData method here? And also, i think object parameter is of no use. As you creating objectparameter variable and again passing only string value to your method. You can skip and directly use dr["..."].ToString() as method parameters.

Comment: @VishalVaishya U updated my Stored procedure code. please have a look into that.

Comment: is your SP's number of parameters are correct. In SP it is 5 and while calling you are passing only 3. Is that correct ?

Comment: Hi my mistake. In my code I am passing all parameters properly, here i forgot to update code. But this is not the problem. Here idSubAccount and idCategory has same values for all three rows, so I think this is the problem I am having. How can I save record one by one in this case if i have same idSubaacount and idCategory values?

Comment: write insert statement instead of update statement in your stored procedures